# CSS: key-frames from -> to with percentage height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do collapse with CSS only. I did something like that, but it's not working. I think is problem with dynamic height because when I add a height in px everything is works. What should I do?

```
@-moz-keyframes collapseIn {
    from {height: 0%;}
    to {height: 100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes collapseIn {
    from {height: 0%;}
    to {height: 100%;}
}

@keyframes collapseIn {
    from {height: 0%;}
    to {height: 100%;}
}
@-moz-keyframes collapseOut {
    from {height: 100%;}
    to {height: 0%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes collapseOut {
    from {height: 100%;}
    to {height: 0%;}
}

@keyframes collapseOut {
    from {height: 100%;}
    to {height: 0%;}
}

.collapseCSS.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation: collapseIn 1s;
    -moz-animation: collapseIn 1s;
    animation: collapseIn 1s;
}
.collapseCSS.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation: collapseOut 1s;
    -moz-animation: collapseOut 1s;
    animation: collapseOut 1s;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That said, you cannot animate to/from height that is *not set* or is set to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a max-height: 100vh; instead of 100%. If no one does scroll the page when collapse was started - it's working well. ;)

```
.collapseCSS {
    overflow:hidden;
}    
.collapseCSS.ng-enter-prepare{
    max-height: 0px;
}
.collapseCSS.ng-enter {
    animation: ng-enter 1s;
}
.collapseCSS.ng-leave {
    animation: ng-leave 1s;
}
@keyframes ng-leave {
    from {max-height: 100vh;}
    to {max-height: 0vh;}
}
@keyframes ng-enter {
    from {max-height: 0vh;}
    to {max-height: 100vh;}
}
```